# using the stringparm and the powerobjectparm

Tags: structure, powerbuilder

I need help, I have problems with the open event of a window
the first dw just sample data from another dw and the second dw using a structure to display uploaded files

this is the code of event list "open" of my window

```
st_structure st

String ls_usuario, ls_clave, ls_sql,  ls_param,  ls_codveh, ls_ruta
Integer li_SQLCode, li_resultado
Long ll_cant



ls_param = Message.StringParm

il_cod_veh = Long(Mid(ls_param,2,8))

title
dw_2.DataObject="dw_consult"
dw_2.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
ii_veh=dw_2.Retrieve(il_veh)


Here I have problems for it to show me the objects of the structure of the files that I upload


st = Message.PowerObjectParm


il_veh = st.numero[1]

ls_codveh = String(il_veh)

is_extension_archivo =  "PDF"

ll_max_megabyte_size_file = 2

il_max_largo_titulo_file = 150

il_conversor_megabyte_byte = 1048576

is_path_file_download = "c:\tmp"

If not DirectoryExists (is_path_file_download) Then
    li_resultado = CreateDirectory(is_path_file_download)
End If


if_recuperar()
```

When selecting a unit, it opens a window (which is the one I am working on) where it shows me information about that unit with the first dw and that allows me to upload documents and with another dw within this same window it shows me the documents already uploaded

Comment: Where is Message.PowerObjectParm being set?  I'm assuming it happens prior to window open.  If so, it would be better to get the value from Message.PowerObjectParm earlier in the code because some of the other code operations might be causing it to be over-written.  The Message should be considered volatile, get the value as soon as you can.